# H20 cluster - generate the values in a tabular format for pdp plots

Tags: python, h2o, h2o.ai, h2o4gpu, h2o-wave

I am using the h20 cluster to train the model using tuned random forest and plot pdp plots using the below code

```
tx = tuned_rf.explain(test_data, top_n_features=5, include_explanations='pdp')
```

This is returning pdp plots in graphical format the graph is `features vs mean response`  but I want to  get the pdp plots in tabular form(below shows the expected output)

```
Feature          Mean response 
Sub-feature-1      0.18
Sub-feature-2      0.15
```

but right now i am getting the same in graphical format I want to get the output in the tabular format how can I  do this using h20 cluster

Answer (score 0):

have a look at H2O's [partial_plot](https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/performance-and-prediction.html#defining-a-partial-dependence-plot). With `plot=False` you can get just the data that you want for each feature (and target in case of multinomial classification) separately. The features in `explain` method are sorted using variable importance that you can retrieve for most models by using the `varimp` method.